# How to change 2x11 to 3x11 on mtb

Tags: mountain-bike, chain, derailleur, crankset, chainring

Hey I was wondering how you would change a chainset from 2x11 to 3x11 on a Carrera Fury (SRAM components) Thanks

Comment: It seems that SRAM doesn't even have 3x11 components.

Comment: I'd question why you'd want to. There's a big choice of close gear ratios available to you with 2 x 11. If you feel the gearing is too low (or too high) overall, consider replacing the cassette for one with a different range; or possibly one of the chainrings (after ensuring your derailleur(s) can cope).

Comment: the top two things on the list would be a new shifter and a new crankset. Before going any further you might want to check on the cost of just these two items, to give yourself an idea of ballpark cost. I'd be surprised if that doesn't put you off.

Comment: and @Klaster_1 is absolutely right, although Shimano do a couple of 3x11 mtb cranksets. As a result of this, though, you also need to think about whether your new, 11sp Shimano components will be compatible with your existing 11sp sram components.

Comment: Hi Sancho! The current range of Fury has a 2x10 drivetrain. Have you upgraded this to 11spd yourself? We sell these bikes in our store so should be fairly easy for me to check it out, if it is the current 2015 model you have. (silver frame, red forks).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say that you can't if you want to stay with SRAM.

Looking at the list of SRAM cranksets:

- Mountain: https://www.sram.com/sram/mountain/component/cranksets
- Road: https://www.sram.com/sram/road/component/cranksets

There are none that have 11sp and 3 chainrings.

But looking at the spec of the bike that I think you have:
http://www.halfords.com/cycling/bikes/mountain-bikes/carrera-fury-mountain-bike-2015

It appears that it's 2x10, rather than 2x11 (it says 20 gears "SRAM X5 20 speed").  Can you check if it's really 11sp that you need?

If you need 3x10, then you'll need to change the crankset and the left shifter - and possibly the front derailleur - though you can probably get away without it.

You can find a matching X5 SRAM 3x10 crankset online pretty easily e.g. http://www.ebay.com/itm/SRAM-X5-GXP-175-10-Speed-44-33-22-Crankset-/272056712049

Note that going to 3x10 does not give you easier gears.  It just gives you smaller jumps between gears.  If you want easier gears, then there is a much simpler and cheaper solution: get a smaller small chainring, and/or a cassette with a larger big cog.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum you'll need at least a triple front crank.   You can't just attach a third chainring to your existing two.  Depending on what you find, the right crank arm may be integrated and non-removable from the front chainrings.
Of course the new crank arm would require the same bottom bracket fitment as your existing one.... or you're up for a new bottom bracket too and a replacement crank arm on the left side.

Pedals should be fine - there's a good chance they're 9/16" thread, and a very small chance they're 1/2" which is a kids size.

If your front derailer has enough range of motion then it could be okay, otherwise a new front mech.  Some front cages (the bit that pushes the chain about) may not drop low enough to cover the three cranksets.  You'll have to try and see.

Your left gear shifter - if its a friction one it may be okay, but you probably want one with enough cable pull to haul the derailerereureur about three positions.

Good news is you shouldn't need a new chain (although check for chain stretch and replace if its got too much longer.

The rear cassette should be okay.

This answer is not SRAM specific because I don't know a lot about their models.   Someone else who knows their product?

Comment: A new chain will likely be needed as the 3spd chainset will have more teeth than the existing 2spd. You might also need to swap the rear mech as it may not have enough capacity to properly tension the chain if you ever use small front, high rear hear combo.

Comment: @User3875425 not necessarily - it depends how many teeth there are on the big chainring.  If its the same, then all is well.  Fewer teeth may mean too much chain and some links need to come out.  More teeth may require additional links added to the chain.

Comment: I don't know of any 11 spd double cranks that are above a 38/40t. Unless the OP has a custom ratio on their existing cranks. Going to a triple would surely result in a higher tooth count on the largest ring, 42T plus.

Comment: @User3875425 Why bring the back into it?  OP wants to go from a 2x11 to a 3x11.   If the big ring on the triple is the same size as the big ring on the double then no extra chain is required.  If the big on the triple is bigger than the big on the double, then yes, more chain may be required.  Noone has said what the tooth sizes are or will be, OP is asking "is it possible" ?  Everything is possible.